# Differentiating $x^2 \sqrt{2x+5}-6$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I differentiate this function: f(x)= $x^2  \sqrt{2x+5}-6$

I had: I had $2x\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2  \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$ but the correction model said it was I had $2x\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2  \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$

Comment: LaTeX tip: don't use period for multiplication. Use `\cdot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work from the outside in. Begin by differentiating it term by term: $$f\,'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\sqrt{2x+5}\right)-\frac{d}{dx}(6)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\sqrt{2x+5}\right)-0\;.$$

Now you have to calculate the derivative of $x^2\sqrt{2x+5}$. This is a product, so you use the product rule:

$$\left[x^2\sqrt{2x+5}\right]'=x^2\left[\sqrt{2x+5}\right]'+\left[x^2\right]'\sqrt{2x+5}\;.$$

To complete the differentiation you’ll need the derivative of $x^2$, which is *very* easy, and the derivative of $\sqrt{2x+5}$. That one is also pretty easy once you rewrite the function as $(2x+5)^{1/2}$: the power rule and the chain rule will take care of it.

Comment: $2x.\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2 . \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$ ?

Comment: @ZafarS: Not quite: the derivative of $(2x+5)^{1/2}$ is $\frac12(2x+5)^{-1/2}[2x+5]'$, and you forgot that last factor; it comes from the chain rule.

Comment: So that's where the 2 comes from..

Comment: @ZafarS: Yes, exactly. And if it had been $2x^2+5$ inside the square root, for instance, you’d have got an extra factor of $4x$ from the chain rule.

Comment: So is it:  $2x.\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2 . \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$

Comment: @ZafarS: Yes, though you can cancel the $2$’s in the second term.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much, you will be gifted the honour of an 'accepted answer' and my gratefulness!

Comment: @ZafarS: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  y &=& x^2(2x+5)^{1/2} - 6 \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &=& \frac{d}{dx} \Big[ x^2(2x+5)^{1/2} \Big] - \frac{d}{dx}\Big[ 6 \Big], \qquad \textrm{Sum/Difference Rule}\\
  &=& \frac{d}{dx}\Big[x^2\Big](2x+5)^{1/2} + x^2\frac{d}{dx}\Big[(2x+5)^{1/2}\Big] - 0, \qquad \textrm{Product Rule}\\
  &=& 2x(2x+5)^{1/2} + x^2\left( \frac{1}{2}(2x+5)^{-1/2}\cdot 2\right),
  \qquad \textrm{Chain Rule}\\
  &=& 2x\sqrt{2x+5} + \frac{ x^2}{\sqrt{2x+5}}, \qquad \textrm{simplification.}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: I spotted that you used `eqnarray`. [Don't do that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule where $\cfrac {df}{dx} = \cfrac {dg}{du} \cfrac {du}{dx} $ if $f(x) = g(u(x))$ and the product rule where $\cfrac {d}{dx} (uv) = v\cfrac {du}{dx} + u\cfrac {dv}{dx} $

Comment: I had $2x.\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2 . \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$

Comment: Sounds like you need the product rule instead.

Comment: redo it carefully

Comment: @ZafarS: What you have is almost right, but you forgot the chain rule when you differentiated $(2x+5)^{1/2}$: you should get $\frac12(2x+5)^{-1/2}\cdot[2x+5]'$, and you’re missing that last factor.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that was probably for ZafarS, not for me :)

Comment: @gt6989b: Yep; I caught it just before you posted.

Comment: $2x.\sqrt{2x+5} + x^2 . \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{2x+5}}$

Answer (score 0):

$2x . \sqrt{2x+5} + \dfrac{x^2}{2} . \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x+5}}2$

Answer (score 0):

I would use the product rule, which you seem to have tried from your comment above. Here would be the idea:

$\begin{split}
\frac{d[x^2 \sqrt{2x+5} - 6]}{dx}
 &= \frac{dx^2}{dx} \sqrt{2x+5} +  x^2 \frac{d(2x+5)^{\1/2}}{dx} \\
 &= 2x \sqrt{2x+5} + x^2 \frac{1}{2} (2x+5)^{-1/2} \cdot 2 \\
 &= 2x \sqrt{2x+5} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x+5}}
\end{split}
$